# what can i do for this openvpn error

Tags: iptables, openvpn

when i start my openvpn server
this error shows:-

Service deferred error: IPTablesServiceBase: failed to run iptables-restore [status=1]: ['iptables-restore: line 62 failed']: python/context:37,internet/epollreactor:223,internet/posixbase:191,internet/process:260,internet/process:762,internet/process:775,internet/_baseprocess:60,svc/pp:116,svc/svcnotify:26,internet/defer:238,internet/defer:307,internet/defer:323,sagent/ipts:105,sagent/ipts:39,util/error:52,util/error:32
service failed to start due to unresolved dependencies: set(['user', 'iptables_openvpn'])
service failed to start due to unresolved dependencies: set(['user', 'iptables_openvpn'])
service failed to start due to unresolved dependencies: set(['user', 'iptables_openvpn'])
service failed to start due to unresolved dependencies: set(['user', 'iptables_openvpn'])
service failed to start due to unresolved dependencies: set(['user', 'iptables_openvpn'])
service failed to start due to unresolved dependencies: set(['user', 'iptables_openvpn'])
service failed to start due to unresolved dependencies: set(['user', 'iptables_openvpn'])
service failed to start due to unresolved dependencies: set(['user', 'iptables_openvpn'])
service failed to start due to unresolved dependencies: set(['iptables_openvpn'])

what can i do to solve this error

thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

if it is not VPS/VDS:

```
# modprobe ipt_mark
# modprobe ipt_MARK
```

Also check TUN/TAP:

```
# cat /dev/net/tun
```

Comment: cat: /dev/net/tun: No such device

Comment: VPS or real server? What OS?